# Dynamically import a module's callable class by walking a directory

Tags: python, dynamic, module

I am trying to dynamically load modules from a directory's subfolders and import all modules dynamically in python.

For clarity on the larger goal: In the javascript version the directory's subfolder name is the name of the adapter. Anything else in that subfolder that doesn't share the exact adapter name is considered an extension to that adapter and should be imported by the adapter code itself.

```
api_adapters
 |
 adapter1
 |      |
 |      adapter1.py
 |
 adapter2
        |
        adapter2.py
        |
        adapter2-extension.py
```

I can do this in javascript with the following code:

**node.js**

```js
  function loadAdapters() {
    let adapterDirs = await readdir('./src/api_adapters', { withFileTypes: true }, (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      const dirs = files
      .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
      .map((item) => item.name)
    })

    let apis = {}
    let adapters
    for(let api in adapterDirs){
      adapters = await readdir('./src/api_adapters/'+ adapterDirs[api].name)
      for(let adapter in adapters){
        apis[adapterDirs[api].name] = await import('../src/api_adapters/' + adapterDirs[api].name + '/' + adapters[adapter])
      }
    }
    return { apis, adapters }
  }
```

How do I do the same with python?

**python**

```py
    from os import walk


    def load_adapters(self, path):
        api_adapters = {}
        for folder in os.scandir(path):
            api_adapter = folder.name
            filename = next(walk(path + '/' + folder.name), (None, None, []))[2]  # [] if no file
            api_adapters[api_adapter] = filename

            from folder.name import file # stuck here
```

I'm fairly new to python, so all help is appreciated.